# Gitlab post-receive hook Host key verification failed

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitlab

I'm having 3 servers:

werkstation.example.com -> server where the gitlab repository is cloned & for changing the files fom the repository

git.example.com -> gitab server with repository "tomcat"

docker.example.com -> server where the files will be copied with git hook

My git hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
read oldrev newrev refname

REPO="git@git.example.com:michaelv1234/tomcat.git"
BRANCH=`echo $refname | sed -n 's/^refs\/heads\///p'`
BRANCH_DIR="/home/michael"
SSH_DEST="michael@docker.example.com"

if [ "$newrev" -eq 0 ] 2> /dev/null; then
# branch is being deleted
echo "Deleting remote branch $SSH_DEST $BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"
echo "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh
ssh  "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh <<-EOF
            cd "$BRANCH_DIR" && rm -rf $BRANCH
    EOF
else
    # branch is being updated
    echo "Updating remote branch $SSH_DEST $BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"
    ssh "$SSH_DEST" /bin/sh <<-EOF
            { cd "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH" || mkdir -p "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH" && cd "$BRANCH_DIR/$BRANCH"; } \
            && { git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/$BRANCH || { git clone "$REPO" ./ && git checkout $BRANCH; }; }
    EOF
fi
```

But i'm still receiving this error:

```
michael@werkstation:~/tomcat$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 254 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating remote branch michael@docker.example.com /home/michael/master
remote: Host key verification failed.
To git@git.example.com:michaelv1234/tomcat.git
0032c02..6e8ef97  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Rights files & directories:

```
custom_hooks directory:
drwxr-xr-x 2 git git 4096 May 27 12:05 custom_hooks

post-receive file in custom_hooks:
rwxr-xr-x 1 git git 1435 May 27 12:05 post-receive
```

I have already removed the "known_hosts" file on every servers but i'm still getting the error

Comment: You can try the following command ```GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ...``` to get more verbose output

Comment: still the same output with the command

Comment: it is strange. As alternative you can enable debug in ~/.ssh/config file. Just add ```LogLevel DEBUG3``` option to the ```git.example.com``` host

Comment: which command must i run after i add this?

Comment: Just ```git clone ...```

Comment: output: git clone git@git.example.com:michaelv1234/tomcat.gitCloning into 'tomcat'...
remote: Counting objects: 39, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 39 (delta 3), reused 27 (delta 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (39/39), 2.87 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection is initialized, the server authenticates itself to the client. The client then checks if the key is already in the known_hosts file. If not, it will prompt the user. This is why, on the first SSH connection, you get a prompt asking you if you want to accept a key with fingerprint xyz. The servers public key is then written to the known_hosts file.

If you never SSH'ed to the server, it is not in the known_hosts file and automatic connections will fail. The easiest way around this is to SSH into the server yourself as the user which is supposed to tun the git command, and answer 'yes' on the prompt.

Comment: I have already SSH'ed to the server. But still get the eroor

Comment: Did you do it as the same user the script runs at? You could also try adding the server hostkey to the global known_hosts file.

Comment: Gitlab runs the script. i don't now which user Gitlab use. The script is in    /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/MYGROUP/MYREPO.git/custom_hooks/post-receive. Git is the owner of custom_hooks.

Comment: There is your problem. The global known_hosts file is /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts per default. Try adding the servers RSA-HOSTkey into that. Otherwise, try to find out which user Gitlab is using. cat /etc/passwd if there is no gitlab it is probably nginx or www-data. You don't have a shell as www-data but you can temporarily gain one by editing passwd.

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
On the Gitlab server:

```
sudo su - git
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id michael@docker.example.com
ssh michael@docker.example.com
```